# How is it possible to show the 'Single user installation' checkbox in InstallShield 2012 Express?

Tags: installshield-2012

I want to make a setup which installs all exes and dlls in the Windows program folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\) and other files in the Windows data folder (e.g. C:\ProgramData\). But even if I select 'per-user' installation, all users can see and launch the installed program. 
I intend to provide users with the option to install the software in either the per-user or per-machine context if possible with the Express version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This settings has the desired effect:

1. General Informations: Set ALLUSERS=2

4: Dialogs: Global Dialog Settings: Set Show All Users Option=Yes (All Systems)